# Recursive Pathfinding in Swift - find longest path

Tags: swift, algorithm, recursion, sprite-kit, path-finding

*(Sorry for the cross-post, but I put this up on GameDev.Stackexchange and it's not getting much traffic, so I thought I'd try here as well.)*

I'm programming a simple tile-based puzzle game, and I've gotten stuck trying to work out a pathfinding algorithm.

Here's how the game is set out:

- The game board is (arbitrarily) 8 tiles wide by 8 tiles tall.
- Each tile can be one of four types (shown below as red, green, blue and yellow)
- Additionally, a tile could be a *reactor* (the starting point of a path - this will become clear later on)

The board would look something like this:

[image: board state 1]

(The reactors are the circles; the other tiles have no special properties.)

What I need to do is: starting from a reactor, trace the longest path along adjoining tiles of the same color as the reactor. Something like this:

[image: board state 2]

The blue reactor is simple(ish) as its path doesn't branch. However, as you can see from the green reactor's start position, its path can branch two ways at the start (up or down), and take a detour midway through.

The path I'm looking for is the longest one, so that's the one that's highlighted in the screengrab (the first path only crosses two tiles, and the detour midway results in a sorter path).

When certain conditions have been fulfilled, the reactor will cause all the tiles in the longest path (where the arrows cross in the diagram) to disappear and be replaced with new ones. All other tiles will remain in place, including the extraneous green tiles adjacent to the green reactor's path.

The tiles are stored in an approximation of a 2D array (Swift doesn't have a robust native implementation of that yet, so I'm using the one described in [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/75270/make-game-like-candy-crush-with-swift-tutorial-part-1)). They're retrieved using `tile[column, row]`.

With some help from a friend, I've written a recursive function that *should* return the longest path. It's looping through correctly, but it's not pruning shorter branches from the `longestPath` array (for example, the longest path would include the 2-tile branch below the reactor, as well as the single-tile detour at the top of the arch).

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong in this code?

Here's the recursive function:

```
func pathfinder(startingTile: Tile, pathToThisPoint: Chain, var iteration: Int? = 1) -> Chain
{
    var longestPath: Chain? = nil

    var availableTiles = getNeighbouringTiles(startingTile)

    for var nextTile = 0; nextTile < availableTiles.count; nextTile++
    {
        let column = availableTiles[nextTile].column
        let row = availableTiles[nextTile].row

        if tiles[column, row]!.tileType == startingTile.tileType && (tiles[column, row]!.isReactor == false || startingTile.isReactor)
        {
            // if we haven't been here before
            if !pathToThisPoint.tiles.contains(tiles[column, row]!)
            {
                print(iteration)
                iteration = iteration! + 1

                // add this tile to the pathtothispoint
                // go to the next unexplored tile (recurse this function)
                pathToThisPointaddTile(tiles[column, row]!)

                let tempPath = pathfinder(tiles[column, row]!, pathToThisPoint: pathToThisPoint)



                // if the resulting path is longer...
                if tempPath.length > longestPath.length
                {
                    // then tempPath is now the longest path
                    for var i:Int = 0; i < tempPath.length; i++
                    {
                        let tile = Tile(column: pathToThisPoint.tiles[i].column, row: pathToThisPoint.tiles[i].row, tileType: pathToThisPoint.tiles[i].tileType)
                        longestPath?.addTile(tile)
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        if longestPath != nil
        {
            return longestPath!
        }
        else
        {
            return pathToThisPoint
        }
    }
```

It's dependent on the getNeighboringTiles function (shown below) that returns an array of valid tiles of the same type, excluding reactors:

```
func getNeighbouringTiles(tile: Tile, previousTile: Tile? = nil) -> Array<Tile>
{
    var validNeighbouringTiles = Array<Tile>()
    var neighbourTile: Tile
    // check top, right, bottom, left
    if tile.row < NumRows - 1
    {
        neighbourTile = tiles[tile.column, tile.row + 1]!
        if neighbourTile.tileType == tile.tileType && !neighbourTile.isReactor && (previousTile == nil || previousTile != neighbourTile)
        {
            validNeighbouringTiles.append(neighbourTile)
        }
    }
    if tile.column < NumColumns - 1
    {
        neighbourTile = tiles[tile.column + 1, tile.row]!
        if neighbourTile.tileType == tile.tileType && !neighbourTile.isReactor && (previousTile == nil || previousTile != neighbourTile)
        {
            validNeighbouringTiles.append(neighbourTile)
        }
    }
    if tile.row > 0
    {
        neighbourTile = tiles[tile.column, tile.row - 1]!
        if neighbourTile.tileType == tile.tileType && !neighbourTile.isReactor && (previousTile == nil || previousTile != neighbourTile)
        {
            validNeighbouringTiles.append(neighbourTile)
        }
    }
    if tile.column > 0
    {
        neighbourTile = tiles[tile.column - 1, tile.row]!
        if neighbourTile.tileType == tile.tileType && !neighbourTile.isReactor && (previousTile == nil || previousTile != neighbourTile)
        {
            validNeighbouringTiles.append(neighbourTile)
        }
    }
    // if we get this far, they have no neighbour
    return validNeighbouringTiles
}
```

The Tile class looks like this (methods omitted for brevity):

```
class Tile: CustomStringConvertible, Hashable
{
    var column:Int
    var row:Int
    var tileType: TileType // enum, 1 - 4, mapping to colors
    var isReactor: Bool = false

    // if the tile is a reactor, we can store is longest available path here
    var reactorPath: Chain! = Chain()
}
```

And finally, the chain class looks like this (again, methods omitted for brevity):

```
class Chain {
    // The tiles that are part of this chain.
    var tiles = [Tile]()


    func addTile(tile: Tile) {
        tiles.append(tile)
    }

    func firstTile() -> Tile {
        return tiles[0]
    }

    func lastTile() -> Tile {
        return tiles[tiles.count - 1]
    }

    var length: Int {
        return tiles.count
    }
}
```

**----------------------- EDIT : REPLACEMENT PATHFINDER ------------------------**

I've attempted to convert [User2464424](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464424/user2464424)'s code to Swift. Here's what I've got:

```
func calculatePathsFromReactor(reactor: Tile) -> Chain?
{
    func countDirections(neighbours: [Bool]) -> Int
    {
        var count: Int = 0
        for var i:Int = 0; i < neighbours.count; i++
        {
            if neighbours[i] == true
            {
                count++
            }
        }
        return count
    }

    var longestChain: Chain? = nil
    longestChain = Chain()
    var temp: Chain = Chain()
    var lastBranch: Tile = reactor
    var lastMove: Int? = reactor.neighbours.indexOf(true)




    func looper(var currentTile: Tile)
    {
        if currentTile != reactor
        {
            if countDirections(currentTile.neighbours) > 2 //is branch
            {
                lastBranch = currentTile
            }
            if countDirections(currentTile.neighbours) == 1 //is endpoint
            {
                lastBranch.neighbours[lastMove!] = false // block move out of the last branch found

                if longestChain.length < temp.length
                {
                    longestChain = temp
                }
                currentTile = reactor // return to reactor and redo
                lastVisitedTile = reactor
                temp = Chain() //reset to empty array
                lastBranch = reactor
                lastMove = reactor.neighbours.indexOf(true)
                looper(currentTile)
            }
        }

        //let tempTile: Tile = Tile(column: currentTile.column, row: currentTile.row, tileType: currentTile.tileType, isReactor: currentTile.isReactor, movesRemaining: currentTile.movesRemaining)
        //tempTile.neighbours = currentTile.neighbours

        if currentTile.neighbours[0] == true
        {
            if !temp.tiles.contains(currentTile)
            {
                temp.addTile(currentTile)
            }
            if countDirections(currentTile.neighbours) > 2
            {
                lastMove = 0
            }
            lastVisitedTile = currentTile
            currentTile = tiles[currentTile.column, currentTile.row + 1]! //must avoid going backwards
            if !temp.tiles.contains(currentTile)
            {
                looper(currentTile)
            }
        }

        if currentTile.neighbours[1] == true
        {
            if !temp.tiles.contains(currentTile)
            {
                temp.addTile(currentTile)
            }
            if countDirections(currentTile.neighbours) > 2
            {
                lastMove = 1
            }
            lastVisitedTile = currentTile
            currentTile = tiles[currentTile.column + 1, currentTile.row]! //must avoid going backwards
            if !temp.tiles.contains(currentTile)
            {
                looper(currentTile)
            }
        }

        if currentTile.neighbours[2] == true
        {
            if !temp.tiles.contains(currentTile)
            {
                temp.addTile(currentTile)
            }
            if countDirections(currentTile.neighbours) > 2
            {
                lastMove = 2

            }
            lastVisitedTile = currentTile
            currentTile = tiles[currentTile.column, currentTile.row - 1]! //must avoid going backwards
            if !temp.tiles.contains(currentTile)
            {
                looper(currentTile)
            }
        }

        if currentTile.neighbours[3] == true
        {
            if !temp.tiles.contains(currentTile)
            {
                temp.addTile(currentTile)
            }
            if countDirections(currentTile.neighbours) > 2
            {
                lastMove = 3
            }
            lastVisitedTile = currentTile
            currentTile = tiles[currentTile.column - 1, currentTile.row]! //must avoid going backwards
            if !temp.tiles.contains(currentTile)
            {
                looper(currentTile)
            }
        }
    }




    // trigger the function for the reactor tile
    looper(reactor)

    return longestChain
}
```

(The `neighbours` property is a `struct` containing four named variables: `above`, `right`, `below` and `left`, each initialised to `false` and then set to `true` by a function that runs immediately before the pathfinder.)

I'm finding a couple of issues now. The code loops as it should, but stops at the top of the arch, under the single-tile detour - the path that's returned is only 4 tiles long (including the reactor).

The other problem I'm having - which I'll worry about when the correct paths are being returned - is that I'm getting a memory access error when shifting the tiles in the third column down by one. I think it's getting confused when there's a block of tiles (2x2 or higher) rather than a path that's only ever a single tile wide.

Comment: Longest path is hard, if the green one could go up 3 (`tile[1,0]= green`) it can go R3 R1 D1 R1 D3 to get the longest path, but finding this way recursive will need you to update the path to a point on the path later on, which isn't that easy i think.

Comment: have you looked at gamekit's pathfinding.  it does pathfinding for you with very little code.  not sure if it would get longest path though.  people are usually looking for the longest way to get somewhere not the shortest..

Comment: I've not looked at Game Kit yet, chiefly because of code portability; if I can get a solution that works without resorting to plugins or code libraries (other than Sprite Kit), then I should be able to port it to other platforms without too much restructuring. If I lean too heavily on Game Kit, I'd need to find comparable frameworks for every other platform.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fix your code, but i have an idea for a system that doesn't require recursion.
You can try doing all possible paths from a reactor and block paths that you already traversed by being aware of the moves you have done when encountering a branch.

In the tile class, add another array of 4 integers initialized to 0 (called "dir" for example).

Pseudocode.
Do a preprocess loop first:

```
foreach tiles:
  if tileHasNORTHNeighbor: tile.dir[0] = 1;
  if tileHasEASTNeighbor: tile.dir[1] = 1;
  if tileHasSOUTHNeighbor: tile.dir[2] = 1;
  if tileHasWESTNeighbor: tile.dir[3] = 1;
```

Then do:

```
tile currentTile = reactor;
array longest;
array temp;
tile lastBranch = reactor;
int lastMove = any key of "reactor.dir" with "1" as value;

function int countOnes(array dir):
  int count = 0;
  int t;
  for (t=0;t<4;t++):
     if dir[t]==1:
        count++;
  return count;


:start
if currentTile != reactor:
  if countOnes(currentTile.dir) > 2: //is branch
     lastBranch = currentTile;
  if countOnes(currentTile.dir) == 1: //is endpoint
     lastBranch.dir[lastMove] = 0; // block move out of the last branch found
     if longest.length < temp.length:
        longest = temp;
     currentTile = reactor; // return to reactor and redo
     array temp = []; //reset to empty array
     lastBranch = reactor;
     lastMove = next "reactor.dir" key with "1" as value;
     goto start;

if currentTile.dir[0] == 1:
  temp.append(currentTile);
  if countOnes(currentTile.dir) > 2:
     lastMove = 0;
  currentTile = getTileAtNORTH; //must avoid going backwards
  goto start;
if currentTile.dir[1] == 1:
  temp.append(currentTile);
  if countOnes(currentTile.dir) > 2:
     lastMove = 1;
  currentTile = getTileAtEAST; //must avoid going backwards
  goto start;
if currentTile.dir[2] == 1:
  temp.append(currentTile);
  if countOnes(currentTile.dir) > 2:
     lastMove = 2;
  currentTile = getTileAtSOUTH; //must avoid going backwards
  goto start;
if currentTile.dir[3] == 1:
  temp.append(currentTile);
  if countOnes(currentTile.dir) > 2:
     lastMove = 3;
  currentTile = getTileAtWEST; //must avoid going backwards
  goto start;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - I've translated your code into Swift, and I can see how it should work... however, it's falling at the first hurdle (I've manually set up a board with a green reactor in [0, 0] and a green tile in [0, 1], but the pathfinder doesn't move beyond the reactor). I'm going to keep chipping away at it to see what I need to fix.

Comment: @MassivePenguin I edited my post a couple of times right after posting so make sure you are traslating the latest version. Now, if the preprocess went correctly, the reactor should have `dir[2] = 1`(south) and the [0,1] tile has `dir[0] = 1`(north). The main loop goes straight to the `if currentTile.dir[2] == 1:` condition as currentTile is reactor and has south flag active. The code will then set `currentTile = getTileAtSOUTH;` and repeat. Please post your code in your OP, probably in this case i can help debugging or somebody else.

Comment: I've made a little progress, but the function is exiting before it should - it's only returning a path (`chain.tiles`) that's four tiles long, including the reactor.

Comment: @MassivePenguin I seen your code and i think you screwed the latest 2 conditions at the end after `if currentTile.neighbours[2] == true`. The `countDirections(currentTile.neighbours) > 2` condition must happend inside the `if currentTile.neighbours[2] == true` branch. Same with the `if currentTile.neighbours[3] == true` right after.

Comment: Whoops - missed that. I've updated my function to follow your example. It's not returning the shorter path now - instead, it's getting caught in a loop...

Comment: @MassivePenguin Welp these branches are still not quiiite right xd. For the loops, my "must avoid going backwards" comments was supposed to notice these situations. Add another variable called `lastVisitedTile` and update it everytime you change position with the tile you just left. Only move if the destination tile is different than `lastVisitedTile`. Initialize to reactor, and reset to reactor at endpoint.

Comment: @MassivePenguin or every time you move you can check the `temp` list of the currently built chain and see if the tile you are going in is not in the list.

Comment: I've encapsulated each directional callback to `looper` in an if statement that checks if the tile we're moving to is in the `temp.chain` array. That's stopped the endless loop, but the script is still exiting after it reaches the single-tile detour...

Comment: @MassivePenguin ok please update your op with the new code. make sure the branches are fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103478/discussion-between-massivepenguin-and-user2464424).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [BFS Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode) and easily modify it to give you the longest path.

You've got a implementation example [here](http://waynewbishop.com/swift/traversals/). Or you've got at least [SwiftStructures](https://github.com/waynewbishop/SwiftStructures) and [SwiftGraph](https://github.com/davecom/SwiftGraph) github repositories with graph and search algorithms already implemented in swift.

Comment: I've looked into this, but I'm having trouble converting the necessary algorithms into Swift.

Comment: @MassivePenguin I've updated my answer with some online examples of implementations in swift. Hope it helps!

Comment: I've already looked at the first example you mentioned (I've even bought the book) and while the concept is explained, and classes and methods are given, there's not a lot in the book about implementation. For example, I have all the code I need to query a graph, but no suggestion on how to loop through an array and create the graph in the first place. Which is rather frustrating.

Comment: @MassivePenguin Modeling a graph is a different problem. A common way to do it is with an [adjacency list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215617/an-array-of-mutable-arrays-in-swift). You can also check out how they did it on the github repositories I linked in my answer.

Comment: Using SwiftStructures (and the accompanying book), I've managed to populate the graph with the relevant data. I can find the goal vertex by performing a BFS, as you suggested, but now I'm stumbling on how to calculate the longest path between the reactor and the goal. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: @MassivePenguin You've done most of the work. Usually BFS is used to find the shortest path but the raw algorithm will go through all of the possible paths. I'm not sure how SwiftStructures work but the BFS should yield a collection of all the possible paths, it's just a matter of picking the longest. Again, not sure if SwiftStructures already does this but if it doesn't it should be a simple modification to the BFS algorithm.

Comment: The library provides two traversal methods which equate to BFS, but they don't build any collections as it does so. This is something I'll need to implement, but I'm drawing a blank as to how.

Comment: @MassivePenguin You've the pseudo code for the BFS algorithm on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode). With it you should me able to implement a version of the algorithm that suits your needs.

Comment: @MassivePenguin I'm the author of SwiftGraph. Thank you for mentioning it, João. A BFS algorithm, like the one in SwiftGraph, typically returns when it finds the first path (which is provably the shortest path in the case of a BFS) to the goal. If I understand correctly, you're looking for the longest path. That's actually an NP hard problem (meaning it can't be solved easily in a reasonable amount of time): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem
All of that being said, I think it would benefit you to use a more comprehensive graph library like SwiftGraph for your game.